# Fisher information matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics, information-theory

Can Fisher Information matrix be calculated for any matrix? I am doing my work on image processing field for face identification. How can I calculate Fisher information matrix on my input image(which is a matrix of pixels indeed)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [empirical Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observed_information), however you would need to specify a parametric likelihood for your data. Given that you know the form of your likelihood, you can evaluate the Hessian at your parameter values. Intuitively, if the Hessian or curvature of log likelihood is high you are more certain about the parameter estimates. To compute the Fisher information matrix you would then take the empirical average of the observed information matrix.